# Handle user answer

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

The task is that user input a sum of deposit and I could handle it in this context, but isn't like a simple command. **Example:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**My code:**

```
func main () {
    testing()
    NewBot, BotError = tgBotApi.NewBotAPI(configuration.BOT_TOKEN)
    if BotError != nil {
        fmt.Println(BotError.Error())
    }
    NewBot.Debug = true
    fmt.Println("OK", time.Now().Unix(), time.Now(), time.Now().Weekday())
    setWebhook(NewBot)
    updates := NewBot.ListenForWebhook("/" + configuration.BOT_TOKEN)
    //go successfulPaymentListen()
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", configuration.BOT_HOST, configuration.BOT_PORT), configuration.CERT_FILE, configuration.CERT_KEY, nil)
    for update := range updates {

        if update.Message != nil {
            recognizeCommand(update)
        } else if update.CallbackQuery != nil {
            if update.CallbackQuery.Data == "/addFunds crypto" {
                get_data.AddFundsChooseCurrencyCrypto(update, NewBot)
            } else if update.CallbackQuery.Data == "/addFunds qiwi" {
                get_data.AddFundsChooseCurrencyQiwi(update, NewBot)
            } else if strings.Split(update.CallbackQuery.Data, " ")[2] != "" {
                get_data.AddFundsChooseCurrencyCurrentCrypto(update, NewBot, strings.Split(update.CallbackQuery.Data, " ")[2])
                //This function is below
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**get_data.AddFundsChooseCurrencyCurrentCrypto:**

```
func AddFundsChooseCurrencyCurrentCrypto(update tgBotApi.Update, NewBot *tgBotApi.BotAPI, currency string) {
    chatUser := int64(update.CallbackQuery.From.ID)
    msg := tgBotApi.NewMessage(chatUser, "Input a sum of deposit:")
    NewBot.Send(msg)
    //There is I have to handle user answer, but I can't override ListenWebHook
}
```

The problem is that I need ListenWebHook localy( in the function **AddFundsChooseCurrencyCurrentCrypto**) instead of main function

**------------------------ UPDATE ------------------------**

**I have tried this code:**

```
func AddFundsChooseCurrencyCurrentCrypto(update tgBotApi.Update, NewBot *tgBotApi.BotAPI, currency string) {
        chatUser := int64(update.CallbackQuery.From.ID)
        msg := tgBotApi.NewMessage(chatUser, "Input a sum of deposit:")
        NewBot.Send(msg)
         NewBotContext, BotError := tgBotApi.NewBotAPI(configuration.BOT_TOKEN)
         if BotError != nil {
            log.Panic(BotError.Error())
         }
        updates := NewBotContext.ListenForWebhook("/" + configuration.BOT_TOKEN)
        for update := range updates {
            fmt.Println(update)
        }
    }
```

**But error:**

```
panic: http: multiple registrations for /mytokenbot

goroutine 1 [running]:
net/http.(*ServeMux).Handle(0xe38620, 0xc25304, 0x2f, 0xc7dbe0, 0xc00018bec0)
```

Comment: can you provide more information on 'get_data'?

Comment: @MuhammadaliJafari get_data is my package https://prnt.sc/ufzcrx

Comment: Have you tried passing `NewBot` to `AddFundsChooseCurrencyCurrentCrypto` and override ListenWebHook there?

Comment: @MuhammadaliJafari No, but it's good idea. I will try

Comment: @MuhammadaliJafari panic: http: multiple registrations for /mybottoken

goroutine 1 [running]:
net/http.(*ServeMux).Handle(0xe38620, 0xc25304, 0x2f, 0xc7dbe0, 0xc00018bec0)

Comment: can you update your question and post what you've tried?

Comment: @MuhammadaliJafari Did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221365/discussion-between-muhammad-ali-jafari-and-netahaki).

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to register the same url '/mytokenbot' twice with your router. You can find the error in net/http:

https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L2433

In the mux Handle function.

So just look through your code for the register function with servemux, and check how you might be calling it twice.